# Svelte click handler toggle boolean in array from div

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte

The toggle works only if clicking on a **button**, ignores the **div**, seems button triggers some sort of *state* change, how do I get this to work when clicking anywhere ?

ToolBar.ts

```
export default class ToolBar  {
    options:Array<ToolBarOptions>;
    constructor() {
        this.options = [
            new ToolBarOptions(ToolButton.sideMenu,SideMenuIcon,false,true, []),
            new ToolBarOptions(ToolButton.mainMenu,MainMenuIcon,false,true, [ new ToolBarOptions(ToolButton.export,exportIcon,true,true,[])]),
            new ToolBarOptions(ToolButton.entities,EntityIcon,false,true,[]),
            new ToolBarOptions(ToolButton.setting,settingsIcon,false,true,[]),
        ];
    }
}

class ToolBarOptions  {
    disabled:boolean;
    name:ToolButton;
    icon:string;
    show:boolean;
    options:Array<ToolBarOptions>;
    constructor(name: ToolButton,icon:string,disabled:boolean,show:boolean, options:Array<ToolBarOptions>) {
        this.name = name;
        this.disabled = disabled;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.show=show;
        this.options=options;
    }
}

export const enum ToolButton{
    mainMenu="mainMenu",
    export="export",

    entities="entities",
    sideMenu="sideMenu",
    setting="setting",
}
```

App.svelte

```
let toolbarOptions = new ToolBar();


function handleClickOutSide() {
console.log(toolbarOptions.options)
toolbarOptions.options.forEach((o) => {
o.show=!o.show;
});

console.log(toolbarOptions.options)
    <div  on:click={handleClickOutSide } class="toolbar">
  <ul class="">
    {#each toolbarOptions.options as  {name,  icon,options, show }, i}
    <li>
      
      <button on:click={()=>show=!show} name={name} class="flex items-center justify-center relative {toolbarOptions.options.length-1 === i ? "h-10":""}">
        {#if toolbarOptions.options.length-1 ===i}
        <div>100%</div>
        {/if}

        <icon>  {@html icon}</icon>
        <span>
          <svg fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M19.5 8.25l-7.5 7.5-7.5-7.5" />
          </svg>
        </span>

        {#if  options.length >0 }

        <div class="absolute top-10 w-32 bg-black h-10 cursor-pointer  {show ? "hidden":""}">
          <ul class="w-full flex">
            {#each options as  {name,  icon,show }}
            <li class="min-w-full flex items-center h-10 px-2">
                <span class="">  {@html icon}  </span>
                <span class="left-4 w-1/2"> {name}</span>
            </li>
            {/each}
          </ul>
        </div>
        {/if}

      </button>
    
    </li>
    {/each}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure that div is actually clicked, and `handleClickOutSide` actually executed. It could be a css problem, e.g. div does not cover the “outside” area, or cursor-event css prop prevent js event from triggering.

Comment: Hi, so the div is clicked and passes thru to the handler ! yeah I know :(

Comment: Ah ok, add this line to the end of handleClickOutside: `toolbarOptions.options = toolbarOptions.options`.

Comment: In svelte, reactivity is detected by tracking explicit assignment, you want an `=` anywhere you want to notify svelte about a state change. It’s tricky, I failed to identify the problem earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When interacting with each item in a list there are several options that take reactivity into account:

- Use item index access
- Map all items
- Use a dummy assignment

Examples for each:

```js
let items = [
    { name: 'Item 1', checked: false },
    { name: 'Item 2', checked: false },
    { name: 'Item 3', checked: false },
];

const toggleViaIndex = () =>
    items.forEach((e, i) => items[i].checked = !items[i].checked);

const toggleViaMap = () =>
    items = items.map(item => ({ ...item, checked: !item.checked }));

const toggleViaDummyAssignment = () => {
    items.forEach(item => item.checked = !item.checked);
    items = items;
}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1bb41968923841c9986f8ee53f87fc55?version=3.52.0)

Personally, I am not a fan of the dummy assignment, because it looks like a useless statement. You can of course add comments to make it clearer why the statement exists.

---

I would not recommend using classes unless necessary, by the way. It breaks things like the map approach, if the class defines any functions or the prototype matters, because those aspects get lost in the spread.

Also: `click` events on things that are not `button` elements should always have a keyboard equivalent for accessibility; in this case probably an escape press.

You also probably should just set `show` to `false` rather than invert it on click outside.

---

By the way, `ToolBarOptions` could be shortened significantly via TypeScript:

```js
class ToolBarOptions {
    constructor(
        public name: ToolButton,
        public icon: string,
        public disabled: boolean,
        public show: boolean,
        public options: Array<ToolBarOptions>,
    ) { }
}
```